# Formatting a string in Swift and C produces a different result

Tags: c, swift, string

I have the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[argc])
{
     printf("%c%c%c", 10, 56, 240);
     return 0;
}
```

That I translated into Swift as

```
import Foundation

let interpolated = String(format: "%c%c%c", 10, 56, 240)
print("\(interpolated)", terminator: "")
```

But, there's a small difference in the output when saved into a file. The C program outputs:

> 8\360

(3 bytes)

And the Swift program

> 8ð

(4 bytes)

Why is that?

Comment: How did you save it to a file? My guess is that Swift produces UTF-8 by default.

Comment: I simply do `./program > File.txt`

Comment: If Swift is anything like Haskell or Perl, then there's an encoding layer on the file handle (stdout) that tells it how to translate (encode) Unicode text to bytes.

Comment: They are represented using different character sets, if you were to use C with unicode, you'd see the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Swift's `Character`s are Unicode characters, not bytes. `240` is being interpreted as codepoint `U+00F0` which is "Latin Small Letter Eth" ("ð"). After you `print` the string, this character is UTF-8-encoded with 2 bytes `C3 B0` which are shown as `ð` by your viewer program.

Comment: Then how would I get the same output as the C program?

Answer (score 0):

In C, `printf` format specifier `%c` only supports ASCII, i.e in range (0-127).

In Swift, `printf` format specifier `%c` supports Unicode, i.e in a larger range.

Apparently, C `printf` is returning the Octal representation for values above 127. Then, to get the same output as the C program but in a Swift program, you need to conditionally replace the format specifiers by comparing values being lower or greater than 127.

If done manually, you can simply write:

```
String(format: "%c%c\\%o", 10, 56, 240)
```

If you want to automate this behavior, then it's a bit tricky as you'll need to parse the format (maybe with a `try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "%.")`) and rewrite it conditionally to `"\\%o"` when the match is `"%c"` and the corresponding value is `>127`.